# Times of calling application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: differs between iOS 5.x and iOS 6

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, ios6, uiapplicationdelegate, ios5.1

Subj.

In iOS 5.x I have the next consequence of methods calling:

```objective-c
-[UIViewController initWithCoder:]
-[UIApplicationDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]
-[UIViewController viewDidLoad]
-[UIViewController viewWillAppear:]
-[UIViewController viewDidAppear:]
```

But in iOS 6.x it's the next:

```objective-c
-[UIViewController initWithCoder:]
-[UIViewController viewDidLoad]
-[UIViewController viewWillAppear:]
-[UIApplicationDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]
-[UIViewController viewDidAppear:]
```

So... what I gonna do? It's my fault or Apple have changed some logic?

Comment: I am under iOS9 and the order of methods called is like in your example for iOS5

Answer (score 0):

in your main.m

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```