# Global variable in app delegate not saving

Tags: iphone, global-variables, appdelegate

I'm new to iPhone Development so bear with me.
I'm trying to access an array stored in the `AppDelegate` from another view controller but when I do it tells me the array is empty.

I created an `NSMutableAarray` in the `AppDelegate` called containerTypeArray.
I build the array with objects in the `AppDelegate` method called:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

After I initialize and init with objects the size of my array is 92  confirmed by the following NSLog message:

```
NSLog(@"container type size %i", [containerTypeArray count]);
```

I try to reference the array variable in a different view controller.
In this view controller I import the appdelegate.h file and write the following in the view did load method:

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     NSLog(@"count at load %i", [appDelegate.containerTypeArray count]);
```

This time the NSLog count is 0.

Can some one tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called after `viewDidLoad`.

The documentation for [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

> You should use this method (and the corresponding application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method) to initialize your application and prepare it to run. This method is called after your application has been launched and **its main storyboard or nib file has been loaded**, but before your app’s state has been restored. At the time this method is called, your application is in the inactive state.

So the view is loaded before the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method is called.

There's a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293922/times-of-calling-applicationdidfinishlaunchingwithoptions-differs-between-ios) on the timing of these methods.

Comment: On StackOverflow, you show thanks by upvoting and accepting answers. Please. :)